# The best use of time at Visual Studio Launch 2010

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Yes, this is a programming-related question, if a little indirectly.

For better or worse, I am switching from Winforms to WPF in April.  I am also going to be in attendance at the Visual Studio [Launch](http://www.devconnections.com/shows/SP2010VS/default.asp?s=144) in Las Vegas.

I have a real need to get up to speed quickly in WPF, so my question is: 
 **What [sessions](http://www.devconnections.com/shows/SP2010VS/default.asp?c=1&s=144) are going to be the best use of my time?**

I've got some picked out already, but I'm looking for some more advice on how to wade through all the marketing fluff and get some real educational value out of these few days.  I have not been to one of these events before, so I don't really know how much is marketing hype, and how much is solid content.

A couple of the [workshops](http://www.devconnections.com/shows/SP2010VS/default.asp?c=3&s=144) look interesting (VPR02 and VPS02), but I don't know enough about the actual content of these to justify the extra expense right now.  Any thoughts there would be appreciated.

And yes, I do have WPF learning planned other than just these few days in Vegas, but since I'm going to be there anyway, I want to learn as much as I can in the time available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would highly recommend picking up a book on WPF and reading that over (if only just skim reading) before taking any courses. WPF is a pretty steep learning curve (coming from WinForms) and familiarizing yourself with WPF first will make the interactive courses that much better because you'll start with a good background and then be able to ask more advanced questions of the instructor rather than basic ones that a good book could have answered for you...

As for book recommendations, I like [WPF in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988223) at lot, although I see you've listed VB.NET in your tags and this book's examples are written in C#.

Comment: With VS 2010 and the "new" WPF on it's way, do you think I should wait for an updated WPF book or will the current version of WPF in Action be OK?

Comment: From what I've read about WPF 4.0, none of the "basic" concepts change compared with WPF (.NET 3.x) -- WPF 4.0 is mostly about adding advanced features that WPF could use. (It's an incremental improvement, rather than the radical jump that the first version of WPF was...)

Comment: It shouldn't at all be like the move from .NET 1.x to .NET 2.0 where a fair amount of things in .NET 1.x were deprecated completely in .NET 2.0 (if that's what you're worried about...)

Answer (score 2):

Skimming the list (please note I only looked at the WPF section -- the list of all sessions was too long to read the whole thing), the ones that jump out as good for a WPF newcomer are:

- VWP02 - because it looks like it's introductory level and focused on getting productive with the tooling
- VWP03 - because it's important to think about WPF as a business app platform, not just an eye candy platform, and data visualisation is one of the killer features for that
- VWP06 - because it's explicitly introductory